# remove duplicates from a named range Excel via Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 to write a program to read data from Excel.
The Excel file contains two columns of data.
Now I need to remove duplicates from range Excel via Delphi.

If it helps any, the VBA macro code is below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$42").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
        :=xlYes
```

Excel_TLB procedure is below:

```
procedure RemoveDuplicates(Columns: OleVariant; Header: XlYesNoGuess);
```

Notations from VBA help:

> Columns - Variant Array of indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate information.

My code is below:

```
procedure TForm1.PuskBClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FExcel, FSheet, FBook: Variant;
  MyColumns: OleVariant;
begin

// open file
 if OpenDialog.Execute then
  begin
// create Excel
   FExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
   FExcel.Visible := true;

   if not VarIsEmpty(FExcel) then // if not empty then
    begin
// open real file Excel and define workbook
     FBook:=FExcel.Workbooks.Open(OpenDialog.FileName); 
// off any Alerts
     FExcel.DisplayAlerts := false; 
// define WorkSheet
     FSheet := FBook.WorkSheets[1]; 
// create array for define columns numbers
     MyColumns:= VarArrayCreate([1,1,1,2], varVariant);
     MyColumns[1,1]:=1; // column 1
     MyColumns[1,2]:=2; // column 2
//call the procedure
     FSheet.Range['A1','B42'].RemoveDuplicates(MyColumns[1,1], xlYes);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This code works fine, but the calculation is only done on the first column. If I change the index, then the calculation is only done on the second column.

```
FSheet.Range['A1','B42'].RemoveDuplicates(MyColumns[1,**2**], xlYes);
```

How should I specify an array for two columns at once?

Comment: 1. `VarArrayCreate([1,1,1,2], varVariant);` creates 2-dimensional array. Probably you need a 1-deminsional.
2. `RemoveDuplicates(MyColumns[1,1], xlYes);`. Have you tried simply passing `MyColumns` ?

Comment: As @OldSkull pointed out - you need to use single dimensional array consisting of 2 values (column indices). To create such an array you can use `VarArrayOf` function. Then you would simply call: `FSheet.Range['A1','B42'].RemoveDuplicates(VarArrayOf[1, 2]), xlYes);`

Comment: Thank you @Old Skull 
1. I have change the array to 1 dimensions. 
`MyColumns:= VarArrayCreate([1,2], varVariant);
     MyColumns[1]:=1;
     MyColumns[2]:=2; `
2. Yes I tried simply passing MyColumns but after execute get Error - the parameter is specified incorrectly. So sad.

Comment: Thank you! Need to use procedure so:
`FSheet.Range['A1','B42'].RemoveDuplicates(VarArrayOf([1,2]), xlYes);` That's right!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to edit the solution into the answer, or to add SOLVED. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Tigor, Although your problem is solved, can you tell me what version of Excel do you use? I tried with Office 365 2021 and `RemoveDuplicates` from Delphi doesn't work. No errors, just nothing happens. If I do it manually in Excel it works.

Comment: @OldSkull  I'm using Excel 2007, but I want to try it with Excel 2013

Comment: @OldSkull this may be possible when using the `UsedRange`. Therefore it's more correct to use the `Range` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

Need to use procedure so:

```
FSheet.Range['A1','B42'].RemoveDuplicates(VarArrayOf([1,2]), xlYes);
```

or so:

```
FSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates(VarArrayOf([1,2]), xlYes);
```

Where [1,2] - are indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate information in the Excel worksheet.

That's right.

**Thank you for help me!**

I'm understanding so:

If need to use columns 7 and 20 then you should put

```pascal
VarArrayOf([7, 20])
```

etc.